# How to get the closest number from a List<int> with LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, list, numbers

How to get the closest number from a `List<int>` with LINQ?

For example:

```
List<int> numbers = new List<int>();
numbers.Add(2);
numbers.Add(5);
numbers.Add(7);
numbers.Add(10)
```

I need to find the closest value in the list to number 9. In this case 10.

How can I do this with LINQ?

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by "closer to a List"?

Comment: What numbers, what list, and what have you tried?

Comment: Any kind of code you could provide always helps get your question understood and thusly answered. :)

Comment: Is the list known to be in order?  Does the list contain duplicates?  What should happen if more than one number is "closest"?  How big is the list likely to be?

Comment: The last case mentioned is exceptionally interesting. None of the provided answers seem to be easily manipulated into being 'stable' in a sense that the larger or smaller number is returned consistently.

Answer (score 164, accepted):

If you use [LINQ to Objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query#LINQ_to_Objects) and the list is long, I would use:

```
List<int> list = new List<int> { 2, 5, 7, 10 };
int number = 9;

int closest = list.Aggregate((x,y) => Math.Abs(x-number) < Math.Abs(y-number) ? x : y);
```

This method is slightly more complex than the solution that Anthony Pegram suggested, but it has as advantage that you don't have to sort the list first. This means that you have a time complexity of `O(n)` instead of `O(n*log(n))` and a memory usage of `O(1)` instead of `O(n)`.

Comment: thanks for the answer, so, I don't understand this part: ? x : y, what is the meaning of that?

Comment: That's the condition operator. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx. I use it to choose `x` or `y`, depending on which one is closest to `number`.

Comment: how to find out about the index too? index of the closet number??

Answer (score 50):

If you want to use LINQ to perform this task, you can do it like below.

```
List<int> list = new List<int> { 2, 5, 7, 10 };
int number = 9;

// find closest to number
int closest = list.OrderBy(item => Math.Abs(number - item)).First();
```

Comment: The disadvantage of this solution is that it has to order the list first, which hurts performance if the list is long. See my answer for a solution that returns the value in `O(n)` time.

Comment: @Elian, I agree. Mine is perhaps more readable. I would have argued for a general loop to avoid LINQ entirely if performance was not good enough, but I have my own job to do. ;)

Comment: I would prefer to use LINQ instead of extension methods. However, this is still beautiful code. No premature optimization, just simple clean code. + for that.

Answer (score 6):

The solutions above are all `O(N)` at best.

If you have a big list and you perform this closest-element query multiple times, it would be more performant to sort the list first ( `O(NlogN)` ) and then use `List<T>.BinarySearch` for each query. The performance for `k` queries is `O( (k+N)logN )`, in comparison to `O(kN)` of the previous method.

Answer (score 4):

These days there also exist a nice and simple option:

```
List<int> list = new List<int> { 2, 5, 7, 10 };
int number = 9;

int min = list.Min(i => (Math.Abs(number - i), i)).i;
```

Answer (score -1):

You could you the binary search. It is the build in method in c# that will help you search for the number closest. Here example: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y15ef976(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: A binary search requires the list to be sorted first, and that can hurt performance.

Answer (score -5):

Use this get nearest lower or Higher based on condition You used.

```
 List<int> list = new List<int> { 2, 5, 7, 10 };
 int number = 9;
 var closest = list.Where(numbers => numbers > number).First();
 Console.WriteLine(closest);
 Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: This returns the wrong result if the match is not below the searched number. In the example, if you search for 8, 10 would be returned.