# Open scaled image file in WP 8.1 app from LocalCache

Tags: c#, image, windows-phone-8.1, image-scaling

I develop a Windows Phone 8.1 app that downloads some data from our server and copy these files into the `ApplicationData.Current.LocalCacheFolder` folder. There are also pictures in the folders with different scaling’s. For example:

- image.scale-100.png
- image.scale-140.png
- image.scale-240.png

The problem is that I cannot access this files without passing the correct file name. If I try to open *image.png* it will fail. But if I try to open e.g. *image.scale-140.png* it works well.

If I insert the images into my project Folder as a resource the app decides which image has the correct scaling for the Display and choose them.

Can I get my app to choose the right image automatically? Or must I determine the scaling manually and determine which images exists?

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
Windows.Graphics.Display.DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView().RawPixelsPerViewPixel;
```

This is the required scaling, so you could try to find the image that's the closest to the actual required scaling, for example like this:

```
var possibleRatios = new List<double>();
possibleRatios.Add(1.0);
possibleRatios.Add(1.4);
possibleRatios.Add(2.4); //etc.
double ratio = Windows.Graphics.Display.DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView().RawPixelsPerViewPixel;
double closest = possibleRatios.Aggregate((x,y) => Math.Abs(x-ratio) < Math.Abs(y-ratio) ? x : y);

string imageName = "image.scale-" + (int(closest * 100)).ToString() + ".png";
```

The algorithm for finding the closest scaling was taken from the answer to this question:
[How to get the closest number from a List with LINQ?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5954005/4735059)

Comment: I impemented even this idea currently into the app. But the main problem is, that I have to check which files exists to determine the correct file name. Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe you could make a Scaling class that can be constructed from a string like 120, 140, etc. Then you could just iterate through the files your filenames, extract the scaling string and choose the best suited file.