# Huge list of long & search nearest element

Tags: c#, list, search

Here is the situation.

I have some objects that contain:

- a starting `long`
- an ending `long`
- a `string` code

These objects `longs` are sequential.
For example:

```
var obj1 = new {From = 0, To = 16777215, Code = "aaa"};
var obj2 = new {From = 16777216, To = 16777471, Code = "bbb"};
```

there are almost 150.000 objects like this.

For the moment I store everything in a SQL table.

The issue is I need to search from this list. For example, I need to look for the object with the number 16777470, which will be the object 2 "bbb".

**Question** : Is there an efficient way to store such an amount of objects in memory and being able to seek for elements in it, having a long and looking for the closest element ?

Comment: On a sorted list, Binary search can work.

Comment: Even if the objects average 50 bytes, that's less than 8MB total: would fit in the cache of many contemporary CPUs. Ie. not huge.

Comment: And it needs to be necessary on memory? because there're efficient ways to do that on SQL.

Comment: It is already in SQL at the moment, but I'm afraid of it because this lookup will happened thousands times per minutes, I don't want to overload the database that is already highly solicited :).

Answer (score 1):

If the objects are sequential then you only need to store the 'from' number.

```
var obj1 = new {From = 0, Code = "aaa"};
var obj2 = new {From = 16777216, Code = "bbb"};
```

This will save memory.

Then, if all the objects are in an ordered list a binary chop should address the efficient search.

The main performance hit may well be in setting up the lists in the fist place, so I think the suggestion to stay with an SQL database may be wise.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure from a memory efficiency point of view.

Thinking: You certainly don't want to search the entire list either, so some kind of secondary structure may be required (some kind of index or lookup????).

Anyway I stumbled across this:
[How to get the closest number from a List<int> with LINQ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5953552/how-to-get-the-closest-number-from-a-listint-with-linq)

Suspect this method might be a bit processor intensive, as it doesn't have a secondary index.

Hope this helps.