# How can I find the closest number to int x, among all the values in an int array?

Tags: c#, arrays, windows

I've recently started learning C# and now I am making a Windows Form Application.

First I have an array of int here:

```
int[] myArray = new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
```

and also, I want to read the value (int) that user entered.
Here I declare it as below.

```
int userInput = Textbox.Text;
```

What I want to do with these two things is, among the values in `myArray`, I want to find out the closest one to the value of `userInput`.

And I want to store the closest number in another array, because I will repeat the this same action for several times and analyze which number came up most often.

I apologize for my unclear explanation, I'm still learning English.
Thank you!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5953552/how-to-get-the-closest-number-from-a-listint-with-linq

Comment: Is `myArray` sorted array?

Comment: Well, I just created an array and randomly put some values.

Answer (score 1):

```
int usernumber = 3; //Get input from textbox
int[] myArray = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };
var nearest = myArray.OrderBy(x => Math.Abs((long)x - usernumber)).First();
```