# Get the number from list using LINQ with specific conditions

Tags: c#, linq, math

I have a list of numbers, I would like to get the next `>=` number than the one I pass, but there's a problem when I pass value that's bigger to the biggest in list. For example when I pass `41` and the biggest in list is 40 it won't work so I'd like it to return 40.

```
var numbers = new[] {30, 20, 40};
```

I would like it to work like:

```
numbers.GetNearest(45) -> 40
numbers.GetNearest(40) -> 40
numbers.GetNearest(31) -> 40
numbers.GetNearest(30) -> 30
numbers.GetNearest(29) -> 30
numbers.GetNearest(1) -> 20
```

Is this possible with LINQ alone, or is there any well-known algorithm for this?

What I have now is something like:

```
numbers.OrderBy(n => n).FirstOrDefault(n => n >= minute)
```

but it doesn't work when I pass value bigger than 40

I don't want the closest number, but the next one `>=` than the one I pass, but for certain numbers bigger than the biggest in list won't work so I'd like to return just the last one.

Comment: Your title talks about "specific conditions" but you don't describe what those are. We can *maybe* guess from the code that you've written, but as you've said that doesn't work, it's hard to say for sure. Please provide more details about what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the closest number from a List<int> with LINQ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5953552/how-to-get-the-closest-number-from-a-listint-with-linq)

Comment: Do you want the nearest bigger number and in case it does not exist then the nearest smaller number? That is the only way your cae of 31->40 and 45 -> 40 can be explained?

Comment: @peeyushsingh yeah

Comment: What is there is no items in `numbers` array? There will be no last one number.

Comment: @apocalypse fair point, I can just check if it's empty first and return 0, but it depends on the case.

Comment: why not try an extension method on int arrays?

Comment: @apocalypse this quesion is not about exception handling

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define that special case with `DefaultIfEmpty()`

```
var numbers = new[] { 30, 20, 40 };
Array.Sort(numbers);
int result = numbers.Where(n => n >= minute).DefaultIfEmpty(numbers.Last()).First();
```

Testcases: https://dotnetfiddle.net/nIEsRO

Comment: This is not pure `Linq`.

Comment: @apocalypse since the input is a array, I'd prefer `Array.Sort(numbers);` over `numbers = numbers.OrderBy(x => x).ToArray();` because it's faster

Comment: @fubo: Yeah I know. But what if we have array of 1,000,000 numbers? What if we don't want to modify input array? Or we don't have array but IEnumerable?

Comment: The answer is [DefaultIfEmpty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.defaultifempty?view=netframework-4.7.2). The fact that there is an `Array.Sort` is irrevelant.

Answer (score 3):

**Update**

```
var numbers = new[]{30, 20, 40};
var number = 25;
var closest = numbers.OrderBy(n => n)
                     .Cast<int?>()
                     .FirstOrDefault(n => n >= number) ?? numbers.Last();
Console.WriteLine(closest);
```

***Note*** : The Cast is just to handle 0 due to `default(int)` maybe a better way to do this though

**output**

```
30
```

[Full Demo Here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/u55XRo)

---

**Original**

You could just order by the difference

```
var closest = numbers.OrderBy(x => Math.Abs((long)x - number))
                     .First();
```

Comment: what if I want it to return 30 when I pass 21,22,23 or 24?

Comment: @Konrad why would you want that? That's not the nearest number. Update your question and explain what you actually want

Comment: Then that is not the nearest

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I don't know the term for that

Comment: @Konrad the term for *what*? In any case, if you want an arbitrary condition pass a different lambda to `OrderBy`

Comment: I think it's unfair to downvote this given that is answered the original question.

Comment: Having said that, the `Cast` in the update is absolutely horrible.

Comment: @DavidG Yeah i guess your right, i have pizza though :P

Comment: Though default for an int = 0

Comment: Recommending awful code means you should have that pizza taken off you. You should know better...

Answer (score 1):

You didn't provide enough details about specific conditions, so I can only give you this answer:

```
var numbers = new[] {30, 20, 40};

var ordered = numbers.Select(x => (int?)x).OrderBy(x => x);

int? value  = ordered.FirstOrDefault(x => x >= 41) ?? ordered.LastOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

Someone posted an answer with `Aggregate` but not working exactly how I wanted it to work but deleted it. So I came up with my own solution using `Aggregate` which should be faster than using `OrderBy` first I think:

```
numbers.Aggregate((x, y) =>
{
    var min = Math.Min(x, y);
    return number <= min ? min : Math.Max(x, y);
});
```

It took me a while to figure it out but it solves my problem. If you can see any flaws in it, let me know.